# Indexing of Spark 3 Dataframe into Apache Solr 8

Tags: apache-spark, solr, lucene, solrj, solrcloud

I have setup a small size Hadoop Yarn cluster where Apache Spark is running.  I have some data (JSON, CSV) that I upload to Spark (data-frame) for some analysis. Later, I have to index all data-frame data into Apache SOlr. I am using Spark 3 and Solr 8.8 version.

In my search, I have found a solution [here](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr#index-parameters) but it is for different version of Spark. Hence, I have decided to ask someone for this.

Is there any builtin option for this task. I am open to use SolrJ and pySpark (not scal shell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Till now [Lucidword](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr) spark-solr module does not support these versions of Spark (3.0.2) and Solr (8.8). I have first installed [PySolr](https://pypi.org/project/pysolr/) module and then use following example code to finish my job:

```
import pysolr
import json

def solrIndexer(row):
    solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/spark-test')
    obj = json.loads(row)
    solr.add(obj)

#load data to dataframe from HDFS
csvDF = spark.read.load("hdfs://hms/data/*.csv", format="csv", sep=",", inferSchema="true", header="true")

csvDF.toJSON().map(solrIndexer).count()
```

If there is some better option or improvement in above code, you are welcome to answer.

Comment: Doesn't this send an update command to solr for each document, or does pyspark batch it automatically? I was looking for a way to batch my updates and stumbled onto this question.

Comment: Its inserts data for each document but its commit is disabled and is executed at the end only

Comment: So it fires a request to solr for each document but doesn't commit them to the index? Or it fires the request only when commit is called?

Comment: Yes, it fires solr for each request but do not commit to index